# How to retrieve sum of data from two tables with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables like below

Book

```
id TID reserveddate fee1 fee2 fee3 Noofplayers total
-------------------------------------
1   11  2012-11-25 100  200  300      3        800
2   12  2012-11-25 100  200  300      3        800
3   13  2012-11-28 200  100  200      1        500
```

Players

```
 TID  fee1 fee2 
-------------------------------------
  11  100  200  
  11  100  200  
  11  100  200 
  12  100  200  
  12  100  200
  12  100  200
  13  200  100
```

now i would like to retrieve data from both tables with group by Reserveddate.

I have a query,

```
select sum(b.fee1)+sum(b.fee2)+sum(a.fee3) as total 
from Players b,book a where a.TID = b.TID  and a.ReservedDate ='25-nov-2012' 
group by a.ReservedDate
```

the above query in sum(fee3) adding 3(noofplayers) times i want to add one time book table.

could you please update the query as per client requirement...

Comment: Which client's requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would work, it would give total of 2400:

```
select  sum(b.fee1_fee2_totalPerPlayer) + sum(a.fee3) as total 
from    book a
join    (
            select  TID,
                    sum(fee1) + sum(fee2) 
                        as fee1_fee2_totalPerPlayer
            from    Players
            group   by TID
        ) b on
        a.TID = b.TID
where   a.ReservedDate ='2012-11-25' 
group by a.ReservedDate
```

Here is how the total is getting calculated:

For TID=11: 300 (sum of Players.fee1) + 600 (sum of Players.fee2) = 900

For TID=12: 300 (sum of Players.fee1) + 600 (sum of Players.fee2) = 900

900 + 900 = 1800

1800 + 600 (sum of Book.fee3 for date '2012-11-25') = 2400

Here is an example: **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9079/2/0)**

Answer (score 0):

So you want to `SUM` per day? You could use a CTE with `SUM(...)OVER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT b.id, b.TID AS bTID, b.reserveddate, b.fee1, b.fee2, b.fee3, b.Noofplayers
     ,    p.TID AS pTID,  p.fee1 AS pFee1, p.fee2 AS pFee2
     ,    SUM(b.fee1 + b.fee2 + a.fee3) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ReservedDate), 0)) As total
     ,    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ReservedDate), 0) AS ReservedDateDay
   FROM Book b INNER JOIN Players p ON b.TID=p.TID
)
SELECT total FROM CTE WHERE ReservedDateDay='20121125';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that *noofplayers* is the number of entry in the *players* table you could simply divide the sum of *fee3* by *noofplayer*

```
select sum(b.fee1)+sum(b.fee2)+(sum(a.fee3)/noofplayer) as total 
from Players b,book a where a.TID = b.TID  and a.ReservedDate ='25-nov-2012' 
group by a.ReservedDate
```

If you are not sure *noofplayer* is correct, you could filter players table on same record like

```
select sum(b.fee1)+sum(b.fee2)+sum(a.fee3) as total 
from book a 
join (select distinct TID, fee1, fee3 from players) as b
on a.TID = b.TID
where  a.ReservedDate ='25-nov-2012' 
group by a.ReservedDate
```